# Getting connection returns false even when the device has connection

Tags: android, networking

I have an app that has an alarmlistener that returns position and send it to a server, but firts it checks the internet connection. This is the method that checks the connection:

```
public boolean hasInternetConnection() {        
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager
                    .getActiveNetworkInfo();            
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable()            
                    && networkInfo.isConnected()) {                     
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;                   
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Permissions on the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="pe.com.hacom.taxitrack.mgr.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

And it has been working fine, but when I tried it on a Motorola XT316 it didn't work, it always return false, even when the device has connection, I check it openning the internet browser and it shows the webpage normally, but the alarm still returning false with that method.

I tested it in other devices and it works fine with all, but that Motorola, any idea what is happening? is that a hardware bug?

And the most rare thing is that sometimes I can get the device in DDMS for the logs on the debug but almost always it appears "Offline". 
I have installed the driver that is in the device, also uninstalling it and installing the universal driver of motorola from the webpage, and its working with Motoroal RAZR's but not with the XT316.

Comment: is `connectivityManager` or `networkInfo` `null`?

Comment: What permissions do you have in the manifest?

Comment: Check my updates please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was testing a lot and I found that many times when I'm asking for connection the NetworkState is "Connecting" so I change the method where I ask for connection.

```
public boolean hasInternetConnection() {        
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager
                    .getActiveNetworkInfo();            
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
                {                     
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;                   
                }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I read the documentation on Google's developer page and found that it is not recommended to use the [isConnectedOrConnecting()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnectedOrConnecting()) method if you're sending or receiving data from the internet, but I think that the BatteryManagment of some devices maybe cut the connection or maybe it doesn't get connected because the 3G network in my city sucks.

I know this is not the best practice but is working, and it's strangely sending and receiving data even when the network state is "connecting".

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: Thank you! 
@Swapnil A solution is to wait until the connection is successfully established.

Answer (score 5):

This might be happening because the device have some sort of battery management system, which disables internet connection, and enables it when you open the browser, but it doesn't work when this Alarm is triggered.

Comment: How do you know that? Just guessing or is a known fact that battery management system exists in some devices.

Comment: I've personally seen it. Actually if you attach a device with a USB cable and read logs generated by System, sometimes you will see warns and actions logged by battery management applications. You'll notice that sometimes Log "talks" about disabling features, changing brightnes, etc.

Comment: I have plugged the device and now I think that you are right, I see some logs with "PowerManagerService" tag between the logs of my app that I never saw in the other devices that I have tested, but is there any way to avoid this service or any way to get the alarm works fine?

Comment: I'm not sure about that... Because most of those applications are coded by manufacturers. But now you can perform some more specific search. BTW, I'd love to know whoever voted negative, why did he vote it negatively.

Comment: Any news about this issue? I have the same problem. I do not know to get connectivity when the phone is in power saver mode.